# Hive table EOF error near 'Customer' 'ID' ')'

Tags: hive

I'm trying to query data for a class project in Hive. I have built an external table with the following columns: Zip code, state, customer id, sales, and date. My next step is to query the data to bring up the top 5 states with the most customers. I keep getting the following error when using this command:

```sql
SELECT State, COUNT(Customer ID) AS NumCustomers
FROM salesrecords
GROUP BY State
ORDER BY NumCustomers DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpQP7.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: column name cant be `customer ID` with a space in between. Please use correct column name.

Answer (score 0):

column name cant be `customer ID` with a space in between. Please use correct column name.  You can use it with backtick(`) like below.

```
SELECT State, COUNT(`Customer ID`) AS NumCustomers 
FROM salesrecords GROUP BY State 
ORDER BY NumCustomers DESC LIMIT 5;
```